# Laravel Validation Only Validate Regex if Field Not Empty

Tags: regex, laravel, validation, laravel-5

my form have youtube_url field, its not required..
but if user fill this field, i must validate the url using regex..

```
'youtube_video' => [
    'regex:/(http:\/\/|https:\/\/|)(www.)?(youtu(be\.com|\.be))\/(video\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|v\/)?([A-Za-z0-9._%-]*)(\&\S+)?/'
],
```

the regex works well, but its throw error if field is not fill (empty) .
how can validate only when user fill the field.

Comment: I think the `nullable` rule before your `regex` one will solve your problem.

Comment: @SystemGlitch thanks, its worked...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Request Validation Regex without Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47141616/laravel-request-validation-regex-without-required)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shoul use [nullable rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields) for it:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'youtube_video' => [
            'regex:/(http:\/\/|https:\/\/|)(www.)?(youtu(be\.com|\.be))\/(video\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|v\/)?([A-Za-z0-9._%-]*)(\&\S+)?/',
            'nullable'
        ],
    ]);
```

Comment: The `"nullable"` validation rule is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!